# Asus bu400a some hotkyes not working

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts

So, I install elementary OS Freya and see that wireless switcher hotkey is not working (Fn + F2) and ambient light sensor switcher (Fn + A). Are any ways to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think there is no solution form developer. Although latest elementary os is included "automatically adjust brightness", It is not work on ASUS Zenbook UX305CA.